# Rails 5, Rolify - removing role from user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, roles, rolify

I am really struggling to understand something that is fundamental to writing code in rails. I don't know what it is to ask a more fundamental question, but i seem to be having similar problems repeatedly.

I have managed to setup rolify in my Rails 5 app. I use rolify to assign roles to users.

Now, I'm trying to setup a function to remove roles from users after they are assigned.

In my user index, I have;

```
<% user.roles.each do |role| %>
  <%= role.name.titleize %> <br>
<% end %>
```

That shows the roles that have been assigned.

Then, Im trying to add:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', role, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

My destroy method is defined in my assign_roles controller. It has:

```
def destroy

    user = User.find(params[:users])
    # role = AppRole.find(params[:roles])
    assigned_role = user.roles
    # user_roles = user.roles
    # organisation = Organisation.first
    # byebug

    user.remove_role assigned_role.name, @current_user.organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully removed"
    redirect_to action: :index
  end
```

The routes are:

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
    scope module: :users do
      resources :assign_roles
    end
```

There isn't an assign_role.rb model. I just use a controller and a view.

When I try to use the destroy role link in my user index, I get an error that says:

```
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

Can anyone see what I need to do to get the assign_roles#destroy action to work?

My create action in the assign_roles controller works. It has:

```
def create
    user = User.find(params[:users])
    role = AppRole.find(params[:roles])
    # organisation = Organisation.first
    @organisation = Organisation.find(@current_user.organisation)
     # byebug

    user.add_role role.display_name, organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to action: :index
  end
```

**Entire assign roles controller:**

```
class Users::AssignRolesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    # if @current_user.is_admin?
      @app_roles = AppRole.all
    # else
    #   @app_roles = AppRole.where(category: relevant_category)
    # end

    # if @current_user.is_admin?
        @users = User.all
   #  else 
      #   @users = current_user.organisation.users.select { |u| u.id != current_user.organisation.owner_id }
    # end  
  end


  def create
    user = User.find(params[:users])
    role = AppRole.find(params[:roles])
    # organisation = Organisation.first
    @organisation = Organisation.find(@current_user.organisation)
     # byebug

    user.add_role role.display_name, organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

  def show
    # @users = User.joins(:profiles).where('profiles.organisation_id = ?' @current_user.organisation.id)
    # @users = User.all
    @current_user.organisation.users
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy

    user = User.find(params[:users])
    # role = AppRole.find(params[:roles])
    assigned_role = user.roles
    # user_roles = user.roles
    # organisation = Organisation.first
    # byebug

    user.remove_role assigned_role.name, @current_user.organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

end
```

**I CAN DO WHAT I WANT TO DO FROM THE CONSOLE - I CANT FIGURE OUT HOW TO DO IT FROM THE CODE**

In the console, I can write:

```
u.remove_role :fff, Organisation.first
```

That then successfully removes the role.

This is fine as a test, but in the code I'm trying to use current_user.organisation instead of Organisation.first. My objective is to allow a user to manage roles on its own organisation only.

In my assign roles controller, I have the destroy action copied above.

In my users index, I have an attempt to delete the assigned role from the user as:

```
 <% user.roles.each do |role| %>
              <table class="table table-bordered">
              <tr>
                <td><%= role.name.titleize %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Remove role', role,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

The error says:

```
undefined method `role_path' for #<#
```

I wonder if I need to give it something else in the path so that it can find the assign roles#destroy action?

When I rake routes | grep assign, I can see:

```
 DELETE   /assign_roles/:id(.:format)                                             users/assign_roles#destroy
```

I tried changing the path in my users index to:

```
<% user.roles.each do |role| %>
              <table class="table table-bordered">
              <tr>
                <td><%= role.name.titleize %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Remove role', assign_role_path(user),  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
              </tr>  
              </table>
             <% end %>
```

But then that gives this error:

```
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

I don't understand what this error means.

**Another clue**

Right, so I can see where the problem arises. I'm out of ideas for how to fix it.

In the console, I can successfully remove a user's role in the way I want to by doing this:

```
u.remove_role :sdfddd, Organisation.first
  Organisation Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "organisations".* FROM "organisations" ORDER BY "organisations"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Role Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND "roles"."name" = $2 AND "roles"."resource_type" = $3 AND "roles"."resource_id" = $4  [["user_id", 4], ["name", "sdfddd"], ["resource_type", "Organisation"], ["resource_id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "users_roles" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND "users_roles"."role_id" = 6  [["user_id", 4]]
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
```

In the code, my current destroy action from the assign roles controller, which says:

```
def destroy

    # user = User.find(params[:users])
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    # role = AppRole.find(params[:roles])
    assigned_role = user.roles
    # user_roles = user.roles
    organisation = Organisation.first
    # organisation = Organisation.find(current_user.organisation)

    # byebug

    user.remove_role assigned_role.name, organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

shows this process in the log:

```
User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Organisation Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "organisations".* FROM "organisations" ORDER BY "organisations"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Role Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND "roles"."name" = $2 AND "roles"."resource_type" = $3 AND "roles"."resource_id" = $4  [["user_id", 4], ["name", "Role"], ["resource_type", "Organisation"], ["resource_id", 1]]
```

The second parameter is a "Role", where maybe it should be the name of the role (i think). Role is a table name.

I'm not sure how to plug this in to make this work. Can anyone see how I can get code to process in the way I can do it in the console?

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

My new attempt at the destroy action in the assign_roles controller has:

```
def destroy

    # user = User.find(params[:users])
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    # role = AppRole.find(params[:roles])
    assigned_role = user.roles
    # user_roles = user.roles
    # organisation = Organisation.first
    organisation = Organisation.find(current_user.organisation)

    # byebug

    user.remove_role assigned_role, organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

I think the problematic line is this one:

```
assigned_role = user.roles
```

It should be the specific role that I am trying to destroy (from the user's array of assigned roles).

The log shows:

```
[["user_id", 4], ["name", "#<Role::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f887ddb9c98>"], ["resource_type", "Organisation"], ["resource_id", 1]]
```

The role shouldn't be an array. It should be a specific role. So, my next guess is to try adding the role to the link in my users index, which is now:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove role', assign_role_path(user, role),  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Then, I need ideas for how I can rewrite the assigned_role line in my destroy action so that it knows which role I am trying to un-assign from the user.

I don't have any good ideas for how to do that.

```
# role = AppRole.find(params[:roles])
assigned_role = user.role
# user_roles = user.roles
```

Any ideas that might help push this thought forward?

Comment: could you please show `index` method?

Comment: what does the log show?

Comment: Just before `user = User.find(params[:users])` print your params hash via `puts params`. My guess is that you should be using `user = User.find(params[:id])` or `user = User.find(params[:user_id])`

Comment: I can't set another bounty to try to find help with this until I earn some more points. Meanwhile, I'll keep posting my attempts & hope I stumble upon the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to destroy the role for just one User, right?
So

```
params[:users]
```

shouldn't be plural, and :users isn't a valid key for params.

You're basically trying to

```
User.find(nil)
```

which fails with

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

You probably should use

```
User.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Hi Eric. No, I'm looking to remove the role from the user. I can assign roles with the assign roles create action. I'm now looking for how to remove assigned roles from users (not the user itself)

Comment: Edited, thanks. Do you have the whole error message and backtrace? On which line does your code raise an exception? `Couldn't find User with 'id'=` would mean that your code cannot even try to remove a role. params[:users] still looks unusual for Rails.