# Rails 5 - Rolify - trying to remove an instance of a role from a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rolify

I am trying to learn how to use rolify with my Rails 5 app.

I've previously asked lots of questions about Rolify, most recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229414/rails-5-rolify-removing-role-from-user) but I've not been able to find help.

Im struggling to try to figure out how to remove an assigned role from a user.

The tables in my schema have tables for app_roles (which is my CRUD for making the roles that can separately be assigned to users), users, roles and user_roles - as:

```
create_table "app_roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "display_name"
    t.integer  "category"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer  "failed_attempts",        default: 0,  null: false
    t.string   "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.integer  "organisation_id"
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["unlock_token"], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "users_roles", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
    t.index ["user_id", "role_id"], name: "index_users_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id", using: :btree
  end

create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.integer  "resource_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.index ["name", "resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_roles_on_name_and_resource_type_and_resource_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_roles_on_name", using: :btree
  end
```

The associations are:

User

```
rolify strict: true # strict means you get true only on a role that you manually add
  attr_accessor :current_role
```

Role

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles

  belongs_to :resource,
             :polymorphic => true,
             :optional => true
```

App Roles (has no associations - It's the CRUD I use to make new roles via a form)

My user model has:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify strict: true # strict means you get true only on a role that you manually add
  attr_accessor :current_role
```

I couldn't figure out how to assign roles just using rolify the way its shown in the wiki. That's why I made a separate resource. It's called assign roles. I have an assign_roles_controller.rb which has:

```
class Users::AssignRolesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
      @app_roles = AppRole.all
  end


  def create
    user = User.find(params[:users])
    role = AppRole.find(params[:roles])
    organisation = Organisation.find(current_user.organisation)
     # byebug

    user.add_role role.display_name, organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

  def show
    @users = User.all
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy

    # user = User.find(params[:users])
    # user = User.find(params[:id])
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    # User.find(params[:id])
    # role = AppRole.find(params[:roles])
    role = params[:user][:roles]
    # assigned_role = user.roles
    # user_roles = user.roles
    # organisation = Organisation.first
    organisation = Organisation.find(current_user.organisation)

    # byebug

    user.remove_role role.display_name, organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

The routes are nested, so I have:

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
    scope module: :users do
      resources :assign_roles
```

In my users index, I'm trying to show a list of users, with each of their roles and a remove role link. In the users/index.html.erb, I have:

```
<% user.roles.each do |role| %>
              <table class="table table-bordered">
              <tr>
                <td><%= role.name.titleize %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Remove role', assign_role_path(user.roles),  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
             <% end %>
```

In the console, I can do:

```
Organisation.find_roles(nil, User.find_by(organisation_id:1))
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."organisation_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["organisation_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Role Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (resource_type IN ('Organisation'))  [["user_id", 43]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Role id: 3, name: "asdf", resource_type: "Organisation", resource_id: 1, created_at: "2016-10-24 23:00:40", updated_at: "2016-10-24 23:00:40">, #<Role id: 4, name: "ffff", resource_type: "Organisation", resource_id: 1, created_at: "2016-11-09 00:26:56", updated_at: "2016-11-09 00:26:56">]>
```

The user has 2 roles.

When I try to remove one of them, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

That error complains about this formulation (which is a copy from someone's suggestion on another SO post) in the destroy action of my assign roles controller:

```
role = params[:user][:roles]
```

When I try the destroy action as:

```
def destroy
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    assigned_role = user.roles
    organisation = Organisation.find(current_user.organisation)

    # byebug

    user.remove_role assigned_role.display_name, organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

I then get an error which says:

```
undefined method `roles' for nil:NilClass
```

I think that error may have something to do with me trying to remove one role from the user but I'm using plural to find them all. I'm not sure how to find the specific one role that I'm referencing in the uses index.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: By simply using rolify you can remove by `user.remove_role :admin`

Comment: No - I'm using scoped roles. That won't work for scoped roles. That's for global roles. Thanks anyway - but it's not what I need.

Comment: One question, in your `link_to 'Remove role'` you should not use `role` instead of `user.roles`?

Comment: @Andrés - I tried it to double check -but no, that doesnt work. Also, that doesnt make sense to me because I'm trying to remove the association between the role and the user (not the role itself). The error currently references the line above (user_roles = user.role) or (    assigned_role = user.roles) - I've been trying various forms of expression for this line, but I can't find one that works.

Comment: in the `destroy` method, first check if the user exist before try to access to `roles` method. Maybe `user` doesn't exist or just the db can't access to the resource. The error `undefined method `roles' for nil:NilClass` it's because `User.find` found nothing

Comment: My console output (copied above) shows that a user is there and has 2 roles

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this once.

```
 def destroy
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    assigned_role = user.role_name
    organisation = Organisation.find(current_user.organisation)

    # byebug

    user.remove_role assigned_role, organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Comment: Hi Atul. thanks for the suggestion. It doesnt work. The reason is that I don't have anything, anywhere, called 'role_name', which is what you suggested that I use in my assigned role variable. Thanks very much anyway for trying to help me. I have tried hundreds of guesses, and am out of things to try.

Comment: Hi Med. Can you please let me know that  are you using Rolify gem?

Comment: Can you please try from your console once.

Comment: What do you suggest I try to do in the console? My post above outlines the relevant roles that the user has - I generated that sql from the console. Do you have a thought as to what to try in the console?

Comment: Please check association. you have AppRoles table where you store created role. You generate migration users_roles where you need to put app_role_id instead of role_id. Please have look above tables. Correct me if i am getting anything wrong.

Comment: Hi Atul - no. That's not quite right. I use the AppRoles CRUD so that I can make roles that can then be assigned to users via the AssignRoles controller. I still have users, roles and user_roles models.

Comment: Hi Med, After reading your all post deeply i got that when we create app_role on that time we need to make entry on role table also. so this may help you in assign and destroy role fron role table.

Comment: For example: you create app_role  name Admin, Then this same name entry will gone on role table also. Please take a look and correct me if am getting wrong.

Comment: I create app_role Admin. AppRoles are then available to assign to users via the AssignRoles controller. When the AppRole is assigned, the user gets a role. I'm trying to figure out how to remove that role, once it is assigned to a specific user.

Comment: role = params[:user][:roles]

Comment: What yo assign here in role its raole name or array /hash

Comment: a user can have many roles   - so the user roles will have an array. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Got to the console and check your user.roles gives you array then you need to check roles table have entry of  name. if yes user.remove_role

Comment: user.remove_role user.roles.first.name, organisation

Comment: I've shown the console output in the post above. Your suggestion won't work (and doesnt work) because the u.roles returns an array of roles. I am trying to find a way to remove one specific assigned role from a user.

Comment: NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object

Comment: yes it return array but when you user.roles.first then it will return first array.

Comment: no - it already found the user. Thank you any way for trying to help me Atul - but this is not the answer. I appreciate the time you've taken to try to help to solve this problem. I'll keep trying to figure this out and will post the answer if I find it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a session on codementor and finally got to an answer.

The answer is:

```
def destroy
#/assign_roles/9?user_id=27
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
    assigned_role = Role.find(params[:id])
    organisation = Organisation.find(current_user.organisation)

    user.remove_role assigned_role.name.to_sym, current_user.organisation #user.organisation

    flash[:notice] = "role deleted"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

And in the view:

```
        <td><%= link_to 'Remove role', assign_role_path(role, user_id: user),  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

The specific issue is that the role name needs to be converted to a string before it can be removed and the user find method is searching in the closest resource (which means it is looking for an id in the role model, not the user model. That means that id will fail to return the user id. I don't understand the search structure of this part of rails - so I have to take that as given (without understanding it), but very happy, that after years of trying to solve this problem, I can move on.